# Issue on Running Image upload on WP Metabox Custom Image Loader

Tags: uploads

Using WP 4.9.4, I am trying to generate a image upload input in custom metabox by using this code inside the Metabox

```
<p>
    <label for="your_fields[image]">Image Upload</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="your_fields[image]" id="your_fields[image]" class="meta-image regular-text" value="<?php echo $meta['image']; ?>">
    <input type="button" class="button image-upload" value="Browse">
</p>
<div class="image-preview"><img src="<?php echo $meta['image']; ?>" style="max-width: 250px;"></div>
```

and in JavaScript I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
      var meta_image_frame;
      // Runs when the image button is clicked.
      $('.image-upload').click(function (e) {
        // Get preview pane
        var meta_image_preview = $(this).parent().parent().children('.image-preview');
        // Prevents the default action from occuring.
        e.preventDefault();
        var meta_image = $(this).parent().children('.meta-image');
        // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
        if (meta_image_frame) {
          meta_image_frame.open();
          return;
        }
        // Sets up the media library frame
        meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
          title: meta_image.title,
          button: {
            text: meta_image.button
          }
        });
        // Runs when an image is selected.
        meta_image_frame.on('select', function () {
          // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
          var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
          // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
          meta_image.val(media_attachment.url);
          meta_image_preview.children('img').attr('src', media_attachment.url);
        });
        // Opens the media library frame.
        meta_image_frame.open();
      });
    });
```

buyt I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frames' of undefined

error at Seting up the media library frame at

```
meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({...});
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I just figure it out that not having `'editor'` in Custom Post Type  support causing this issue but the point is I do not need to  have the editor enabled on this specific post type. Can you please let me know how I can fix this without having  the editor?

Comment: Dose any one has any idea on this, please?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error because I forgot to add:

```
wp_enqueue_media();
```

Then I found this [how to](https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-use-wordpress-media-upload-in-plugin-theme/) and solved the problem like this:

1: You have to enqueue WP JavaScript library for media and your own JS file:

```php
public function enqueue_scripts() {
  //WP library
  wp_enqueue_media();
  //Your JS file
  wp_register_script('name-of-your-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/path-to-your.js', array( 'jquery'), $this->version, true);
  wp_enqueue_script($this->plugin_name);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
```

2: Create html for the form parts

```
<input class="img-01" type="text" name="img-01" size="100" />
<input type="button" class="button wk-button" data="img-01" value="<?php _e('Select image', 'your-text-domain');?>" />
<div><img src="" class="img-01"/></div>
```

3: Add code to your JS file (js/path-to-your.js)

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".wk-button").click(function (e) {
      var wkMedia;
      // Using dynamic selector is useful if you want to use media selection/upload more then once within a single page (this value is populated from data attribute of the button
      var selector = $(this).attr("data");
      // Title is populated from value of the button to make it ready for localization
      var title = $(this).attr("value");
      e.preventDefault();
      // If the upload object has already been created, reopen the dialog
      if (wkMedia) {
        wkMedia.open();
        return;
      }
      // Extend the wp.media object
      wkMedia = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: title,
        button: {
          text: title,
        },
        multiple: false,
      });

      // When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
      wkMedia.on("select", function () {
        var attachment = wkMedia.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();
          $("input." + selector).val(attachment.url);
          $("img." + selector).attr("src",attachment.url);        
      });
      // Open the upload dialog
      wkMedia.open();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering an issue with a custom image upload functionality within a WordPress Megabox. To troubleshoot and resolve this issue, consider the following steps:

1. Check Browser Console:
   Open your browser's developer console (usually by pressing F12 or right-clicking and selecting "Inspect" or "Inspect Element"). Look for any JavaScript errors or warnings related to the image upload functionality. This can give you insights into what might be causing the issue.
2. Check PHP Errors:
   Make sure to enable error reporting in WordPress to see if there are any PHP errors or warnings occurring behind the scenes. You can add the following code to your `wp-config.php` file to enable error reporting:

   ```php
   define('WP_DEBUG', true);
   define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
   ```
3. Check Metabox Code:
   Review the code responsible for handling the image upload in your metabox. Ensure that you're using the correct HTML structure, input field names, and JavaScript functions. Double-check that the necessary libraries (like jQuery) are being loaded correctly.
4. Check AJAX Calls:
   If the image upload uses AJAX to handle the upload and save, verify that the AJAX endpoints are correctly defined and functioning. Check the network tab in your browser's developer console to see if any AJAX requests are failing.
5. Verify File Permissions:
   Ensure that the server has appropriate write permissions for the upload directory. Incorrect file permissions can prevent successful image uploads.
6. Conflict with Plugins/Themes:
   Disable other plugins or switch to a default WordPress theme temporarily to check if there's a conflict causing the issue. Some plugins or themes might interfere with the custom image upload process.
7. Debugging Tools:
   Utilize WordPress debugging plugins or tools, such as Query Monitor or Debug Bar, to gain more insights into what's happening during the image upload process.
8. Testing on Different Environments:
   Test the custom image upload on different environments, such as a local development setup or a staging site. This can help you determine if the issue is specific to your current hosting environment.
9. Consult Documentation and Support:
   If you're using a third-party plugin or framework for creating the custom Megabox and image upload, refer to their documentation or seek support from their community or support channels.
10. Hire a Developer:
    If the issue remains unresolved, consider hiring a WordPress developer with experience in custom meta boxes and image upload functionality. They can analyze your code and debug the issue more thoroughly.