# How to Control CSS of Admin On Creating only a Specific Custom Post Type

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I have a Custom Post Type Called `SlidersCPT` as I register the CPT like

```
register_post_type( 'SlidersCPT', $args );
```

and I need to apply some CSS rules on admin page **only** when creating New SlidersCPT custom Post Type. I thought this might help:

```
if(get_post_type() == 'SlidersCPT') {}
```

but as you can see it just controlling the page of Custopm Post Type not the Admin area.

what I want to do is controlling css of page if it is in admin page of creating a custom post type

```
function hide_editor() { 
 if(get_post_type() == 'SlidersCPT') { ?>
     <style>
       #insert-media-button {  display: none !important; }
    </style>
  <?php
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_style' );
function load_admin_style() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'post.php' === $pagenow && isset($_GET['post']) && 'YOURPOSTTYPE' === get_post_type( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Global `$pagenow` is a subject to tweak. Use [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) instead.

Comment: Hi apavliukov, thanks for comment. I add this solution to `functions.php` but it is not adding the css file into the page on admin panel!

Comment: did you change 'YOURPOSTTYPE' to your post type?

Comment: I did it is  `.. &&  'SlidersCPT' === get_post_type( ... )` now

Comment: Did you create `admin-style.css` containing your CSS rules?

Comment: I did and in fact it is working on removing the `if()` section

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the admin Add screen looks like this:

```
https://example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=SlidersCPT
```

So, check the query string (superglobal `$_GET`) for the post type you try to add:

```
<?php
function hide_editor() { 
    if( isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && 'SlidersCPT' == $_GET['post_type'] ) {
?>
    <style>
    #insert-media-button {  display: none !important; }
    </style>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

**More:**

As CSS is easily tweakable in any modern browser, instead of hiding you can completely remove Add Media button, for example for users with Author capabilities and lower:

```
<?php
function remove_add_media_button(){
    // Check if user is not Author, but Editor or higher
    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_categories' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'media_buttons', 'media_buttons' );
    }
}

if( isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && 'SlidersCPT' == $_GET['post_type'] ) {
    add_action('admin_head', 'remove_add_media_button');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Max but I need to keep the Editor in the post support. Can you please take a look at this Post (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291164/issue-on-running-image-upload-on-wp-metabox-custom-image-loader)? I explained why I need the editor there.

Comment: Your First Css methos also is generating error `Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`

Comment: Oh, sorry, there was is a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks No error this time but CSS is not applying to the admin page

Comment: Despite my proposed code should work, that's the wrong way to manage admin CSS. See @apavliukov answer for the correct implementation.

Comment: Also, the whole idea you mentioned in a previous comment is poor. You have to use built-in WordPress functionality to remove Add Media button and add a custom image upload metabox without any JavaScript usage.